# Mark as unread flag is not working in IMAP + ruby

Tags: ruby, imap, read-unread

Unread to Read

it's working

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(account.imap_url, 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.login(account.client_email, account.client_secret)
imap.select("Inbox")
imap.search(['All'])
imap.store(7665, "+FLAGS", [:Seen])
```

Read to Un-read

it's not working

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new(account.imap_url, 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.login(account.client_email, account.client_secret)
imap.select("Inbox")
imap.search(['All'])
imap.store(7665, "+FLAGS", [:Unseen])
```

I tried with Unseen, Unread, Not seen and I have set a flag as 1, 0 for seen then also I didn't any solution for it.
[Bad Response Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axX8D.png)

Answer (score 3):

Unseen is not a flag (it is a search criteria though).  You take away the `\Seen` flag with -FLAGS instead.